# Unity - how to make material double sided

Tags: unity-game-engine

Search for the issue gives a number of solutions, but they don't work for some reason in mine Unity3D 5.4. Like 
[camera inside a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776151/camera-inside-a-sphere)

I do not see `cull` and/or `sides` in material in Unity editor. 
In C#

```
rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
mater = rend.material;
rend.setFaceCulling( "front", "ccw" );
mater.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

gives no such `setFaceCulling` and `side` property.

How to make material double sided?

Answer (score 16):

You need a custom shader to enable double sided material by using `Cull Off`
The easiest/fastest way to test is to create a new `Standard Surface Shader` in the editor and open it. Add the line `Cull Off` below `LOD 200`.

Now one thing to consider is that lightning will not render correctly for the back faces. If you want that, I would recommend doing models with 2 sides.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! In my tries, it gives the backside a kind of look-through, almost transparent feel, where every color behind it is kind of inverted or so.

Comment: Yeah this will not render the lighting correctly, i.e. the light has to be mirrored!

Comment: The lighting will work correct if you simply apply a view direction to the normal.
ie: Based on normal dot viewdir, flip normal.
The idea is that the normal is only correct in a single direction - but you essentially want lighting from both front and rear views.

Comment: @Akin Erkan Answer down below is the most straight forward as new shaders Unity shaders now have a 'Render Face: Both' now... Be sure to upvote it...

Answer (score 9):

Use or create a shader with

**Cull off**

*Seen here in this simple 2 sided shader:*

```
Shader "Custom/NewSurfaceShader" {
    Properties {
        
    }
    SubShader {
         Cull off   
         Pass {
             ColorMaterial AmbientAndDiffuse
         }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially the same was previous answer, but starting from a default shader might be more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe my answer for your Unity Version doesn't work, but here it is a solution for newer versions in HDRP in image below 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also, In Unity 2020.3 URP/Lit shader has a Render face option guys.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Akin Erkan!

Why is this Answer not Upvoted!

Comment: Let's UPVOTE this answer guys!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, the question is old and there are already upvoted answers, but these kinds of new answers seems like going to take a long time to show up above.

Comment: Doesn't help with SRP

Comment: What a time saver thank you from all my heart

Answer (score 1):

just Creat an **Unlitshader** and edit it:

> > you should write  `Cull off` bellow  *LOD 100*
> > then drag it to a new material and set an picture for test - now drag material to an object .
> > lightning will render correctly !!! ( my unity is 2019.4 )

```
enter code here

Shader "Unlit/unlit"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100
        Cull off
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        } }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom surface shader with **Cull Off** but the opposite faces will not get the light proper, because the normals are valid only for front faces, for back faces the normals are opposite to faces. If you want the back face to be treated like the front face and don't want to make a model with double sides mesh to consume double memory you can draw in 2 **Passes**, 1 **Pass** for front face and 1 for back face where you can inverse normal for every vertex in **vertex shader**. You can use **Cull back** and **Cull front**.

```
SubShader
{
     //Here start first Pass, if you are using standard surface shader passes are created automated, 
     //else you should specify Pass {  }
     Tags { ... }
     LOD 200
     Cull Back

     ...
     struct Input 
     {
         ...
     }
     ...

     ...
     //or vert & frag shaders
     void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard p)
     {
           //processing front face, culling back face
           ...
     }
     ...

     //Here start second pass put automated by unity
     Tags {...}
     LOD 200
     Cull Front

     #pragma vertex vert
     #pragma surface ...

     ...
     struct Input 
     {
         ...
     }
     ...

     void vert(inout appdata_full v)
     {
           v.normal = -v.normal;//flip
     }

     void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard p)
     {
           //processing back face, culling front face
           ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the free unity double sided shader

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/free-double-sided-shaders-23087