# Can't see plane in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, plane

I am working on a game where there will be two different planes and the player will move between the two planes (1st person perspective).

I put the main camera in between two different planes that have equal x and z values and the y values differ by 10.  Right now the camera has a y value of 5 (right in between the two planes).

No matter where I move the camera below the top plane I cannot see it.  I guess technically it’s the bottom of the top plane.

Here is what everything looks like:

[image: Here is an image of the scene view]

Comment: You could also try to create a [double sided shader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42253311/7111561) or Take one from the [AssetStore](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/double-sided-shaders-23087)

Comment: look up "backface culling" thats the "problem" you have. if you just flip the top plane around you will see it. but look up "backface culling" anyway. no easy way out, we are here to understand things ;)

Answer (score 2):

Planes are rendered only in one direction. So if you see the bottom you won't be able to see it.

If you want to see both sides you could use a [cube primitive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrimitiveType.Cube.html) and shrink the `y` scale component to be really thin, or you can make two planes, putting them back-to-back.

In the case you want to set them back to back you can just (1) duplicate the plane (with CTRL + D) and then set the scale of this new plane to 1,-1,1 with the same position of the other. All the other values will stay the same of the other original plane.
Like this:

[image]

You see only one face of the plane because because the [normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_normal) of that plane are pointing upwards, and the default shader only renders surfaces where the normal of that surface (usually an average of the vertices of that surface) is facing the camera.

Most of the shaders are set to cull backfaces. To have a more advanced solution you can simply set CULL OFF in the shader to render both sides.

See also: [Render both sides of a plane - Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/826090/unity-object-plane-render-both-sides-possible.html)

Comment: Adding a box collider lets you see it from below?

Comment: Yes, but if you have both plane and box they would most likely conflict in some way. You could add a box collider, but make sure it doesn't touch the plan. Maybe the best solution is just to copy the plane and just reverse it.

Comment: I see, like one of [these](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrimitiveType.Cube.html)? `Collider`s are invisible without a renderer attached to them